# Delete duplicated lines based in a pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to remove all duplicated lines based in a specific pattern, below you can see a small sample of my file:

```
Jul 22 12:43:57 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:56232 [22/Jul/2021:12:43:57.862] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/3/3 200 402 - - ---- 110/108/8/8/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getAccountInfo api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlk chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlkobnbpdkcdod application/json

Jul 22 12:44:02 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:56232 [22/Jul/2021:12:44:02.436] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/0/0 200 400 - - ---- 111/109/4/4/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getTokenAccountsByOwner api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlk chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlkobnbpdkcdod application/json

Jul 22 12:44:03 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:56232 [22/Jul/2021:12:44:03.033] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/0/0 200 402 - - ---- 111/109/4/4/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getAccountInfo api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlk chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlkobnbpdkcdod application/json

Jul 22 14:11:56 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:37086 [22/Jul/2021:14:11:56.959] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/0/0 200 400 - - ---- 144/142/4/4/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getTokenAccountsByOwner api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjo chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa application/json

Jul 22 14:11:57 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:37086 [22/Jul/2021:14:11:57.559] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/3/3 200 402 - - ---- 136/134/4/4/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getAccountInfo api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjo chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa application/json
```

The only information I care is the chrome-extension ID for example: `chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlkobnbpdkcdod`

*Note:if you guys notice I have 2 patters with `chrome-extension://something` in the same line, one with ID truncated and another with the ID complete, I wish to perform this operation matching the complete one.*

in this example above I have only 5 entries, but in my real file a have a lot of them, I would like to find "chrome-extension://" and remove all lines that have the value of it duplicated.

In this example above my result could be:

```
Jul 22 12:44:03 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:56232 [22/Jul/2021:12:44:03.033] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/0/0 200 402 - - ---- 111/109/4/4/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getAccountInfo api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlk chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlkobnbpdkcdod application/json

Jul 22 14:11:57 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:37086 [22/Jul/2021:14:11:57.559] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/3/3 200 402 - - ---- 136/134/4/4/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getAccountInfo api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjo chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa application/json
```

But it could be any of the 5 entries above, I don't care about which line it will be, it could be sorted, the important thing is to get only one line for each chrome ID.

I tried a few things with awk, sed, sort and uniq, but I'm a noob in Linux and regex, so I would be really grateful if you guys could give me a light.

Comment: please show your attempt

Comment: You have two `chrome-extension://something` per line. Which one do you want to use for this filtering? First, second, any but at same place, any in any order, both? Please try to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: It's the second one @RenaudPacalet which is not truncated. However, I had an answer below using sed that already works for me, but new suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: SO answers are not just for the person who asked. They are also for others that will maybe encounter a similar difficulty one day and search SO for a solution. Please update your question such that it becomes unambiguous.

Comment: I have edited my commentary so that it can clearer. Also I added a few more examples so that the result could give more than 1 output, I think this way will be more helpful for people trying to do the same thing. Thank you very much, your suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is sorted, `uniq` can be told to ignore the first 24 fields using the `-f` option.

```sh
sort file-sample | uniq -f 24
```

Comment: It didn't have the expected result. Although it deleted a few lines and improved the visualization the goal is to have only 1 line based in the value of chrome_extension://

There is an example above using sed which worked perfectly, anyway thank you very much for the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/chrome-extension/{G;/chrome-extension(\S* ).*\1/d;P;s/chrome-extension//g;h;d}' file
```

If a line contains `chrome-extension`, append previous extensions and try and match.

If a match is found, a duplicate exists, so delete the line.

Otherwise, print the line, remove the literal(s) `chrome-extension`, make a copy and then delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '!seen[$25]++' file
Jul 22 12:43:57 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:56232 [22/Jul/2021:12:43:57.862] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/3/3 200 402 - - ---- 110/108/8/8/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getAccountInfo api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlk chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlkobnbpdkcdod application/json
Jul 22 14:11:56 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:37086 [22/Jul/2021:14:11:56.959] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/0/0 200 400 - - ---- 144/142/4/4/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getTokenAccountsByOwner api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjo chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa application/json
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ sort -k25,25 file | uniq -df24
Jul 22 12:43:57 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:56232 [22/Jul/2021:12:43:57.862] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/3/3 200 402 - - ---- 110/108/8/8/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getAccountInfo api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlk chrome-extension://adlbhecpgmnfllbdnbhlkobnbpdkcdod application/json
Jul 22 14:11:56 localhost haproxy[24190]: <IP_ADDRESS>:37086 [22/Jul/2021:14:11:56.959] http-ap~ rpc-ap/localhost 0/0/0/0/0 200 400 - - ---- 144/142/4/4/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1" getTokenAccountsByOwner api.mainnet-beta.solana.com foundation chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjo chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa application/json
```